# QTextEdit.find() doesn't work in Python

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt4, qtextedit

Simple code demonstrating the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTextEdit

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

def findText():
    print(textEdit.find('A'))

textEdit = QTextEdit()
textEdit.show()
QObject.connect(textEdit, SIGNAL('textChanged()'), findText)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After typing 'A' into the window, `find('A')` still returns `False`.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the position of the cursor in the window.

By default - unless you specify some [flags](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtextdocument.html#FindFlag-enum) to be passed to the `find()` function, the search only happens *forward* (= from the position of the cursor onwards).

In order to make your test work, you should do something like this:

1. Run the program.
2. Go to the window and type `BA`
3. Move your cursor to the beginning of the line
4. Type `C`

This way you will have in the window the string `CBA`, with the cursor between `C` and `B` and the string onto which the `find()` method will work returning `True` will be `BA`.

Alternatively you can test this other version of your code that has the backward flag set.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8  -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTextEdit, QTextDocument

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

def findText():
    flag = QTextDocument.FindBackward
    print(textEdit.toPlainText(), textEdit.find('A', flag))

textEdit = QTextEdit()
textEdit.show()
QObject.connect(textEdit, SIGNAL('textChanged()'), findText)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```